# Enforcing one of two checkboxes is selected when using react-hook-form, Yup, and Material UI

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

I'm trying to create a form that has two checkboxes.  I want the validation to ensure that at least one of the two checkboxes is selected when the form is submitted.

The code posted below seems to have (at least) two problems:

1. I'm trying to put the two checkbox values into an array called "topics".  Topics starts as an array when the page loads, but when I check either box, it changes to a boolean value.
2. I am trying to validate that topics has at least one item.  I first tried doing this with yup, as shown in the schema, `array.min(1)`.  Then I tried passing a validate rule to the Controller as described [here](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/register#options). The validate rule never runs.

Can anyone point me towards the proper way of doing this?  I'm not entirely sure if I need to be using Yup for this, or if I need to use a custom validation callback passed to rules.

Thanks.

```js
const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  topics: Yup.array().min(1, 'Select at least one option'),
})

const defaultValues = {
  topics: [],
}

export function AddTopics() {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: {errors, isValid},
    getValues,
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    defaultValues,
  })
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log('data', data)
  }

  return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
          <Stack spacing={1}>
            <FormControl>
              <FormLabel>Topics (select at least one):</FormLabel>
              <FormGroup row>
                <Controller
                  name="topics"
                  control={control}
                  rules={{
                    validate: {
                      topics: () => {
                        console.log('validating (never runs)')
                      },
                    },
                  }}
                  render={({field}) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <FormControlLabel
                          {...field}
                          control={<Checkbox {...field} />}
                          label="Topic 1"
                        />
                        <FormControlLabel
                          {...field}
                          control={<Checkbox {...field} defaultChecked />}
                          label="Topic 2"
                        />
                      </>
                    )
                  }}
                />
                )}
              </FormGroup>
            </FormControl>

            <Button type="submit" variant="contained" color="primary">
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Stack>
        </form>
  )
}
```